# How can I use versioning with SugarCRM's Module Builder?

Tags: php, versioning, sugarcrm

I've created a module using SugarCRM's Module Builder and deployed it. Later, I need to modify (add/remove) fields and relationships from a deployed module. If I make the change in Module Builder and re-deploy the module it will remove all my custom code for the module including the icons I created for the module.

Is there a workflow that enables me to version module code so that it can be re-destributed and worked on by multiple developers?

Answer (score 0):

After after deploying a module it's suggest to continue your customization through the studio instead of modify it in builder and redeploy it.

If you have a team, it's better to manager your package trough GIT or SVN and manage your version with capabilities provide by manifest entries. You could read this entry: https://www.atcoresystems.com/resources/documentation/sugarcrm-manifest-development-guide and more specily the `upgrade_manifest` part

Answer (score 0):

It's never too late!

Use the custom directory will save your life.

---

1) Under:

custom / modulebuilder / builds / MODULENAME / SugarModules / modules / MODULENAME / MODULENAME.php

here you can write your own custom class method.

add to repository the whole "custom / modulebuilder / builds / MODULENAME / SugarModules / modules / MODULENAME /"

2) Choose a whatever folder, in this case "zip" under:

custom / modulebuilder / builds / MODULENAME / zip /

you can put the source module builder package and add the "zip" folder to repository too.

Now each time you want to make a studio operation (for e.g. add/remove a field), once you made it, you can re-export the project and override 
the archive file each time you want to commit.

---

**Custom Icons**

For the icons you need to modify and put on repository the following path "custom / modulebuilder / packages / MODULENAME / icons"

**Production publish**

The cool thing is that here if you go to "MB > PACKAGE > Publish" the generated module will have all your customization.

Comment: I have tried your approach 1): I edited the file at "custom / modulebuilder / builds / MODULENAME / SugarModules / modules / MODULENAME / MODULENAME.php"  . Then I went to SugarCRM module builder and then click Export in my package. However the downloaded zip file did not have any changes to MODULENAME.php . What's wrong? Is there any extra step to do before exporting the module? Thanks